# How to show axis labels in Sparkline charts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, highcharts

**What works?**
I've implemented the example as in this (jsfiddle) demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/sparkline/

**--- Code (JS/CSS/HTML) ---**

```js
/**
 * Create a constructor for sparklines that takes some sensible defaults and merges in the individual
 * chart options. This function is also available from the jQuery plugin as $(element).highcharts('SparkLine').
 */
Highcharts.SparkLine = function (a, b, c) {
    var hasRenderToArg = typeof a === 'string' || a.nodeName,
        options = arguments[hasRenderToArg ? 1 : 0],
        defaultOptions = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: (options.chart && options.chart.renderTo) || this,
                backgroundColor: null,
                borderWidth: 0,
                type: 'area',
                margin: [2, 0, 2, 0],
                width: 120,
                height: 20,
                style: {
                    overflow: 'visible'
                },

                // small optimalization, saves 1-2 ms each sparkline
                skipClone: true
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false,
                tickPositions: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                endOnTick: false,
                startOnTick: false,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                tickPositions: [0]
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                hideDelay: 0,
                outside: true,
                shared: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    animation: false,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 1,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                radius: 2
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    fillOpacity: 0.25
                },
                column: {
                    negativeColor: '#910000',
                    borderColor: 'silver'
                }
            }
        };

    options = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions, options);

    return hasRenderToArg ?
        new Highcharts.Chart(a, options, c) :
        new Highcharts.Chart(options, b);
};

var start = +new Date(),
    $tds = $('td[data-sparkline]'),
    fullLen = $tds.length,
    n = 0;

// Creating 153 sparkline charts is quite fast in modern browsers, but IE8 and mobile
// can take some seconds, so we split the input into chunks and apply them in timeouts
// in order avoid locking up the browser process and allow interaction.
function doChunk() {
    var time = +new Date(),
        i,
        len = $tds.length,
        $td,
        stringdata,
        arr,
        data,
        chart;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        $td = $($tds[i]);
        stringdata = $td.data('sparkline');
        arr = stringdata.split('; ');
        data = $.map(arr[0].split(', '), parseFloat);
        chart = {};

        if (arr[1]) {
            chart.type = arr[1];
        }
        $td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
            series: [{
                data: data,
                pointStart: 1
            }],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + $td.parent().find('th').html() + ', Q{point.x}:</span><br/>',
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}.000</b> USD'
            },
            chart: chart
        });

        n += 1;

        // If the process takes too much time, run a timeout to allow interaction with the browser
        if (new Date() - time > 500) {
            $tds.splice(0, i + 1);
            setTimeout(doChunk, 0);
            break;
        }

        // Print a feedback on the performance
        if (n === fullLen) {
            $('#result').html('Generated ' + fullLen + ' sparklines in ' + (new Date() - start) + ' ms');
        }
    }
}
doChunk();
```

```css
#result {
    text-align: right;
    color: gray;
    min-height: 2em;
}
#table-sparkline {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
td, th {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    height: 20px;
}

thead th {
    border-top: 2px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}
.highcharts-tooltip>span {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
<table id="table-sparkline">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Income</th>
            <th>Income per quarter</th>
            <th>Costs</th>
            <th>Costs per quarter</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>Result per quarter</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody-sparkline">
        <tr>
            <th>Alabama</th>
            <td>254</td>
            <td data-sparkline="71, 78, 39, 66 "/>
            <td>296</td>
            <td data-sparkline="68, 52, 80, 96 "/>
            <td>-42</td>
            <td data-sparkline="3, 26, -41, -30 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Alaska</th>
            <td>246</td>
            <td data-sparkline="87, 44, 74, 41 "/>
            <td>181</td>
            <td data-sparkline="29, 54, 73, 25 "/>
            <td>65</td>
            <td data-sparkline="58, -10, 1, 16 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Arizona</th>
            <td>101</td>
            <td data-sparkline="56, 12, 8, 25 "/>
            <td>191</td>
            <td data-sparkline="69, 14, 53, 55 "/>
            <td>-90</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-13, -2, -45, -30 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Arkansas</th>
            <td>303</td>
            <td data-sparkline="81, 50, 78, 94 "/>
            <td>76</td>
            <td data-sparkline="36, 15, 14, 11 "/>
            <td>227</td>
            <td data-sparkline="45, 35, 64, 83 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>California</th>
            <td>200</td>
            <td data-sparkline="61, 80, 10, 49 "/>
            <td>217</td>
            <td data-sparkline="100, 8, 52, 57 "/>
            <td>-17</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-39, 72, -42, -8 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Colorado</th>
            <td>118</td>
            <td data-sparkline="13, 48, 21, 36 "/>
            <td>273</td>
            <td data-sparkline="98, 86, 8, 81 "/>
            <td>-155</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-85, -38, 13, -45 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Connecticut</th>
            <td>201</td>
            <td data-sparkline="6, 64, 44, 87 "/>
            <td>148</td>
            <td data-sparkline="60, 13, 73, 2 "/>
            <td>53</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-54, 51, -29, 85 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Delaware</th>
            <td>161</td>
            <td data-sparkline="7, 27, 49, 78 "/>
            <td>298</td>
            <td data-sparkline="19, 90, 100, 89 "/>
            <td>-137</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-12, -63, -51, -11 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>District of Columbia</th>
            <td>106</td>
            <td data-sparkline="18, 39, 27, 22 "/>
            <td>185</td>
            <td data-sparkline="62, 97, 24, 2 "/>
            <td>-79</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-44, -58, 3, 20 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Florida</th>
            <td>249</td>
            <td data-sparkline="51, 24, 90, 84 "/>
            <td>244</td>
            <td data-sparkline="47, 40, 74, 83 "/>
            <td>5</td>
            <td data-sparkline="4, -16, 16, 1 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Georgia</th>
            <td>183</td>
            <td data-sparkline="36, 80, 39, 28 "/>
            <td>212</td>
            <td data-sparkline="43, 25, 52, 92 "/>
            <td>-29</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-7, 55, -13, -64 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Hawaii</th>
            <td>232</td>
            <td data-sparkline="73, 34, 74, 51 "/>
            <td>172</td>
            <td data-sparkline="1, 83, 49, 39 "/>
            <td>60</td>
            <td data-sparkline="72, -49, 25, 12 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Idaho</th>
            <td>166</td>
            <td data-sparkline="25, 43, 31, 67 "/>
            <td>152</td>
            <td data-sparkline="30, 30, 75, 17 "/>
            <td>14</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-5, 13, -44, 50 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Illinois</th>
            <td>336</td>
            <td data-sparkline="56, 84, 98, 98 "/>
            <td>151</td>
            <td data-sparkline="61, 12, 77, 1 "/>
            <td>185</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-5, 72, 21, 97 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Indiana</th>
            <td>216</td>
            <td data-sparkline="52, 87, 64, 13 "/>
            <td>216</td>
            <td data-sparkline="2, 47, 94, 73 "/>
            <td>0</td>
            <td data-sparkline="50, 40, -30, -60 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Iowa</th>
            <td>135</td>
            <td data-sparkline="41, 45, 19, 30 "/>
            <td>159</td>
            <td data-sparkline="17, 34, 45, 63 "/>
            <td>-24</td>
            <td data-sparkline="24, 11, -26, -33 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Kansas</th>
            <td>184</td>
            <td data-sparkline="52, 43, 65, 24 "/>
            <td>215</td>
            <td data-sparkline="20, 42, 97, 56 "/>
            <td>-31</td>
            <td data-sparkline="32, 1, -32, -32 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Kentucky</th>
            <td>289</td>
            <td data-sparkline="85, 74, 98, 32 "/>
            <td>219</td>
            <td data-sparkline="37, 38, 93, 51 "/>
            <td>70</td>
            <td data-sparkline="48, 36, 5, -19 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Louisiana</th>
            <td>257</td>
            <td data-sparkline="89, 18, 87, 63 "/>
            <td>201</td>
            <td data-sparkline="19, 54, 35, 93 "/>
            <td>56</td>
            <td data-sparkline="70, -36, 52, -30 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Maine</th>
            <td>194</td>
            <td data-sparkline="17, 68, 61, 48 "/>
            <td>133</td>
            <td data-sparkline="44, 35, 42, 12 "/>
            <td>61</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-27, 33, 19, 36 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Maryland</th>
            <td>204</td>
            <td data-sparkline="74, 12, 74, 44 "/>
            <td>157</td>
            <td data-sparkline="65, 58, 22, 12 "/>
            <td>47</td>
            <td data-sparkline="9, -46, 52, 32 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Massachusetts</th>
            <td>172</td>
            <td data-sparkline="44, 35, 69, 24 "/>
            <td>115</td>
            <td data-sparkline="26, 3, 69, 17 "/>
            <td>57</td>
            <td data-sparkline="18, 32, 0, 7 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Michigan</th>
            <td>177</td>
            <td data-sparkline="99, 26, 13, 39 "/>
            <td>185</td>
            <td data-sparkline="20, 37, 99, 29 "/>
            <td>-8</td>
            <td data-sparkline="79, -11, -86, 10 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Minnesota</th>
            <td>99</td>
            <td data-sparkline="34, 30, 16, 19 "/>
            <td>137</td>
            <td data-sparkline="49, 43, 24, 21 "/>
            <td>-38</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-15, -13, -8, -2 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Mississippi</th>
            <td>205</td>
            <td data-sparkline="38, 75, 31, 61 "/>
            <td>179</td>
            <td data-sparkline="0, 68, 100, 11 "/>
            <td>26</td>
            <td data-sparkline="38, 7, -69, 50 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Missouri</th>
            <td>135</td>
            <td data-sparkline="37, 48, 2, 48 "/>
            <td>202</td>
            <td data-sparkline="41, 64, 17, 80 "/>
            <td>-67</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-4, -16, -15, -32 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Montana</th>
            <td>195</td>
            <td data-sparkline="48, 81, 38, 28 "/>
            <td>237</td>
            <td data-sparkline="44, 33, 86, 74 "/>
            <td>-42</td>
            <td data-sparkline="4, 48, -48, -46 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Nebraska</th>
            <td>286</td>
            <td data-sparkline="98, 55, 82, 51 "/>
            <td>232</td>
            <td data-sparkline="89, 54, 28, 61 "/>
            <td>54</td>
            <td data-sparkline="9, 1, 54, -10 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Nevada</th>
            <td>221</td>
            <td data-sparkline="66, 4, 57, 94 "/>
            <td>214</td>
            <td data-sparkline="59, 39, 94, 22 "/>
            <td>7</td>
            <td data-sparkline="7, -35, -37, 72 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>New Hampshire</th>
            <td>136</td>
            <td data-sparkline="32, 21, 1, 82 "/>
            <td>306</td>
            <td data-sparkline="88, 85, 65, 68 "/>
            <td>-170</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-56, -64, -64, 14 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>New Jersey</th>
            <td>194</td>
            <td data-sparkline="31, 40, 24, 99 "/>
            <td>147</td>
            <td data-sparkline="7, 45, 12, 83 "/>
            <td>47</td>
            <td data-sparkline="24, -5, 12, 16 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>New Mexico</th>
            <td>207</td>
            <td data-sparkline="66, 93, 18, 30 "/>
            <td>261</td>
            <td data-sparkline="97, 28, 79, 57 "/>
            <td>-54</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-31, 65, -61, -27 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>New York</th>
            <td>316</td>
            <td data-sparkline="48, 95, 76, 97 "/>
            <td>193</td>
            <td data-sparkline="68, 5, 97, 23 "/>
            <td>123</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-20, 90, -21, 74 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>North Carolina</th>
            <td>175</td>
            <td data-sparkline="31, 71, 2, 71 "/>
            <td>188</td>
            <td data-sparkline="93, 5, 81, 9 "/>
            <td>-13</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-62, 66, -79, 62 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>North Dakota</th>
            <td>181</td>
            <td data-sparkline="3, 90, 62, 26 "/>
            <td>288</td>
            <td data-sparkline="70, 63, 82, 73 "/>
            <td>-107</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-67, 27, -20, -47 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Ohio</th>
            <td>189</td>
            <td data-sparkline="70, 50, 6, 63 "/>
            <td>163</td>
            <td data-sparkline="21, 94, 4, 44 "/>
            <td>26</td>
            <td data-sparkline="49, -44, 2, 19 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Oklahoma</th>
            <td>188</td>
            <td data-sparkline="66, 46, 53, 23 "/>
            <td>172</td>
            <td data-sparkline="26, 25, 35, 86 "/>
            <td>16</td>
            <td data-sparkline="40, 21, 18, -63 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Oregon</th>
            <td>165</td>
            <td data-sparkline="82, 31, 38, 14 "/>
            <td>257</td>
            <td data-sparkline="91, 9, 80, 77 "/>
            <td>-92</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-9, 22, -42, -63 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Pennsylvania</th>
            <td>268</td>
            <td data-sparkline="33, 88, 82, 65 "/>
            <td>129</td>
            <td data-sparkline="30, 29, 41, 29 "/>
            <td>139</td>
            <td data-sparkline="3, 59, 41, 36 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Rhode Island</th>
            <td>164</td>
            <td data-sparkline="8, 86, 32, 38 "/>
            <td>182</td>
            <td data-sparkline="88, 8, 18, 68 "/>
            <td>-18</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-80, 78, 14, -30 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>South Carolina</th>
            <td>91</td>
            <td data-sparkline="24, 18, 0, 49 "/>
            <td>193</td>
            <td data-sparkline="72, 62, 21, 38 "/>
            <td>-102</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-48, -44, -21, 11 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>South Dakota</th>
            <td>184</td>
            <td data-sparkline="73, 17, 64, 30 "/>
            <td>221</td>
            <td data-sparkline="21, 91, 57, 52 "/>
            <td>-37</td>
            <td data-sparkline="52, -74, 7, -22 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Tennessee</th>
            <td>233</td>
            <td data-sparkline="92, 24, 25, 92 "/>
            <td>131</td>
            <td data-sparkline="5, 18, 42, 66 "/>
            <td>102</td>
            <td data-sparkline="87, 6, -17, 26 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Texas</th>
            <td>211</td>
            <td data-sparkline="33, 80, 68, 30 "/>
            <td>225</td>
            <td data-sparkline="86, 58, 36, 45 "/>
            <td>-14</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-53, 22, 32, -15 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Utah</th>
            <td>362</td>
            <td data-sparkline="89, 98, 96, 79 "/>
            <td>225</td>
            <td data-sparkline="35, 51, 88, 51 "/>
            <td>137</td>
            <td data-sparkline="54, 47, 8, 28 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Vermont</th>
            <td>119</td>
            <td data-sparkline="4, 19, 56, 40 "/>
            <td>152</td>
            <td data-sparkline="17, 66, 27, 42 "/>
            <td>-33</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-13, -47, 29, -2 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Virginia</th>
            <td>127</td>
            <td data-sparkline="24, 27, 41, 35 "/>
            <td>71</td>
            <td data-sparkline="30, 2, 36, 3 "/>
            <td>56</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-6, 25, 5, 32 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Washington</th>
            <td>165</td>
            <td data-sparkline="40, 11, 63, 51 "/>
            <td>245</td>
            <td data-sparkline="46, 41, 94, 64 "/>
            <td>-80</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-6, -30, -31, -13 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>West Virginia</th>
            <td>248</td>
            <td data-sparkline="66, 56, 97, 29 "/>
            <td>171</td>
            <td data-sparkline="65, 53, 37, 16 "/>
            <td>77</td>
            <td data-sparkline="1, 3, 60, 13 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Wisconsin</th>
            <td>183</td>
            <td data-sparkline="24, 55, 21, 83 "/>
            <td>224</td>
            <td data-sparkline="80, 64, 13, 67 "/>
            <td>-41</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-56, -9, 8, 16 ; column"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Wyoming</th>
            <td>231</td>
            <td data-sparkline="52, 49, 97, 33 "/>
            <td>251</td>
            <td data-sparkline="96, 50, 23, 82 "/>
            <td>-20</td>
            <td data-sparkline="-44, -1, 74, -49 ; column"/>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My implementation looks exactly like the example, both visually and code wise.

**What would I like to do now?**

I'd like to add labels with chart information, where the red lines are in the picture below.

[image: Image example]

The picture shows what it currently looks like, albeit the red lines are of course added in mspaint.

**What doesn't work and what have I tried?**

I'd like the charts to show their axis labels, they don't currently show any labels, only information on a tooltip if you hover over them. I've tried setting "enabled" to true for both the y- and the x-axis labels, but nothing seems to change when I do so.

I've also tried enabling "Legend" as I figured maybe that was it, but to no difference. The only difference when i enable "Legend" is that the series in the chart appear so that I can toggle their visibility by clicking them in the legend.

I'm very much open for ideas on how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the labels and also increase the chart `margin` valeus:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    margin: [20, 0, 10, 30]
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b1ozhu26/

Image example: [image]

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.margin

Comment: Had a "sense" earlier that I should have looked more into the margin, but didn't follow up on it yet, thank you :-)